# Java Swing JTable, set the background color of the cell / row to which rows data matches in the array using CustomRenderer

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I would like to change the background of cell in JTable using CustomRenderer where the rows is specified in the arrayOfInt, I have tried this code, it's work fine but I want using array for the rows specified.

```
class CustomRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{

    int[] selected;
    public CustomRenderer(int[] selected){
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        JTextField cell = new JTextField();
        cell.setBackground(((row==2 && col==0) || (row==0 && col==0) || (row==3 && col==0))?Color.YELLOW : Color.WHITE);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

I tried this code but just the last data of array that affect to the table rows, in this code the array is

> {0,2,3}

```
    class CustomRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{

    int[] selected;
    public CustomRenderer(int[] selected){
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        JTextField cell = new JTextField();
        for(int i=0; i < selected.length; i++){
            cell.setBackground(((row) == selected[i] && ((col) == 0) ? Color.YELLOW : Color.WHITE));
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the second code?

Comment: rows 3 affected, because 3 is the last data in the array

Comment: different code but same result, https://prnt.sc/gkmzly

Comment: Try to make your text field opaque (`cell.setOpaque(true)`). Also it would be better to extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for example.

Comment: I have this code

table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomRenderer(new int[]{0,2,3}));
table.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
table.setEnabled(false);
table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
table.setShowGrid(false);
table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
return table;

Comment: @RoyHabeahan please provide a runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we also can reproduce and debug your problem.

Comment: example I have an array `int[] theRow = new int[]{0,1,3};` and JTable.
I want the cell at row that the value is in theRow changed color to Yellow